# iOS - No Product download link xcode server

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, bots, osx-server, xcode-server

I do not see the Product link on one of my Bots. I see it for the other three, but on one, all I see is Archive. I have tried everything in the scheme and settings, but I can't get it to show up. The build succeeds with warnings.

The other difference is that the project is using a Workspace with Pods. Could that be part of the problem as well?